# Filing Form 5500EZ and Plan Characteristics Codes for Line 8

Tags: united-states, income-tax, retirement, irs, solo-401k

I recently shutdown my individual 401(K) plan at E*Trade. There was also a Roth 401(K) plan also. I plan to file form 5500EZ twice, once for each plan. On line 8, I need to put in one or more characteristics codes.

I have selected the code 2J for both plans. It seems to me that there should be a code for a Roth 401(K) but there is not. Is there something I am missing?

I noticed that on the form there is space for up to 10 codes. Here is the description of code 3B.

```
    3B  - Plan covering self-employed individuals.
```

Since I am self-employed and the only person in the plan, should I use code 3B?

Bob

Note: I am in the United States

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't include code 3B. As far as I can tell you are correct about there not being a code for a Roth 401(k).

For more information on Form 5500-EZ, see [this page](https://www.fidelity.com/retirement-ira/small-business/form-5500) from Fidelity (click the 'Form 5500-EZ' tab). If you click on the line numbers on the right, it will give you more information on how to complete it, including the plan characteristics on line 8.

The Finance Buff also has a [good page](https://thefinancebuff.com/form-5500ez-for-your-solo-401k.html) on Form 5500-EZ, including a completed example (be sure to check the comments as well).